# Java reflection: Access methods of classes that extend a class

Tags: java, class, reflection, hierarchy, class-hierarchy

Am developing an interpreter in Java and for easy extensibility, I am using some reflection at startup time so functions can be called just by their name.

So far I had the following structure of classes:

```
A extends B
B extends C
C extends D
```

And to access ALL the methods defined in any of those classes I used:

```
Method method = A.class.getMethod("theExpectedFunctionName");
```

That works.

However now that the project grew it turned out that it would be much more comfortable to have a class structure like:

```
B extends A
C extends A
D extends A
```

But now the getMethod function naturally doesn't work like that anymore.
Is there a way how I can retrieve all methods that are in children classes of A?

Huge thanks in advance!

Comment: `A` doesn't have any way of knowing about the methods of classes that extend it. If you want to get a method from `B`, you need `B.class.getMethod`, not `A.class.getMethod`.

Comment: Hmm, unfortunate if that's the only solution…

Comment: A solution, far from being good, is to scan the classpath and test each class against Class.isAssignableFrom method. Then, for each class that passes the test, get it's methods and put them in a list.